# Mathf.PerlinNoise only returns the float 0.4652731 at every given position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a 2d tilemap based world generationscript but the Mathf.PerlinNoise command only returns 0.4652731!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class WorldGeneration : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Tilemap Tilemap;
    public Tile GrassTile;

    public int width;
    public int height;

    public float threshold;

    void Start()
    {
        Tilemap.ClearAllTiles();

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                Debug.Log(Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, y));
                
                if (Mathf.PerlinNoise(x, y) >= threshold)
                {
                    Tilemap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), GrassTile);
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

After executeing the script there are no errors at all! Why is the Mathf.PerlinNoise command only returning the same number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik [`Mathf.PerlinNoise`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html) generates a pattern with size 1 * 1. Not sure if it not even repeats.

What happens in your case I suspect is that you pass in whole numbers so it always returns the same/similar value.

Try to scale it down to fractions from `0` to `1` like e.g.

```
Debug.Log(Mathf.PerlinNoise(x / width, y / height));
```

See e.g. [this post](https://answers.unity.com/questions/486449/how-does-mathfperlinnoise-work.html) which had exactly the same issue

> all of them printed the same number : `0.4652731`
>
> ```
> function Start () 
> {
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(0, 0));
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(2, 0));
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(0, 5));
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(10, 3));
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(2, 0));
>      print(Mathf.PerlinNoise(1, 1));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`PerlinNoise` doesn't work with integers; use floats instead, like this:

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log(Mathf.PerlinNoise(1.01f, 3.45f));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are passing in integer values to the [`Mathf.PerlinNoise`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html) function. You should scale your x and y values down. Brackeys has a good tutorial on that, I recommend you to watch it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bG0uEXV6aHQ